What does a yellow x2 over an enemy's head mean?
Sometimes when I attack an enemy, a yellow x2 will appear over their head. What does this x2 mean?


The yellow x2 means your attack hit the enemy twice due to Apollo's Extra Dose Boon. It makes every attack have a random chance of hitting twice.

